# How to get Processor ID from any linux command

Tags: bash, java, hardware, cpu

I have a java code

```
HardwareAbstractionLayer hal = new SystemInfo().getHardware();
hal.getProcessor().getProcessorID()
```

From which I am getting `ProcessorId` on my Ubuntu 18 machine

Anyway I can verify that value from any Linux command?

Edit :
I have upgraded the hardware API with code :

```
hal.getProcessor().getProcessorIdentifier().getProcessorID()
```

and now I am getting correct processor ID : `A9 06 03 00 FF FB EB BF`

following command gives the value but with some text

```
sudo dmidecode -t processor | grep -E ID
ID:A9 06 03 00 FF FB EB BF
```

Edit:
Thanks @Steve And @WinEunuuchs2Unix
My Final Command which did the trick is

```
dmidecode -t processor | grep -E ID | sed 's/.*: //' | head -n 1
```

Comment: `sudo dmidecode -t processor`

Comment: i have used it . From it i got multiple information and the Processor is not same in whole. It have multiple information with ID: A9 06 00 FF FB EB BF

Comment: Any help guys in it?

Comment: I take it your are saying after running the command in @FedonKadifell's comment, that you are looking for any linux command to return only the ID and nothing else and if that's the case you can use grep with that command or any command for that matter to return only the processor ID:                                     `sudo dmidecode -t processor |grep -E ID`

Comment: I am seeing that ID return from the java api and this command is bit different. any idea what i am missing?

Comment: Thanks a lot steve. it has worked quite well. just a small extra spaces in start with ID: can you help it in removing it

Comment: @Steve you can add this as Answer as well. this command almost did the trick. I just needed to remove the  starting space and ID: from code at the moment till i doesn't find anything in the command itself to also do the cleansing. Thanks

Comment: This is close to what Steve will post as an answer: `sudo dmidecode -t processor |grep -E ID | cut -d: -f2 | sed 's/^ *//'`

Comment: Even better: `sudo dmidecode -t processor | grep -E ID |  sed 's/.*: //'`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix.  Thanks for suggesting that I should post the answer, but my answer was just a tweak of another answer and yours is the ultimate answer, and I cant post it as I would kind of be taking credit for it but I didn't add the essential sed part removing the ID and only returning the ID number itself.  So I am happy for you to post yours as the final answer as you can explain how the sed part works where I have only dabbled a bit in awk and sed and don't know enough about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:

```
sudo dmidecode -t processor | grep -E ID |  sed 's/.*: //'
```

The `sed` command is used to remove the line prefix: "       ID: " as explained in this popular answer:

- [How to use Sed to replace all characters before colon?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136794/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-all-characters-before-colon)

> #### Explanation:
>
> First part pipes string to `sed`.
>
> The second is a basic sed substitution. The part between the first and
> second / is the regex to search for and the part between the second
> and third is what to replace it with (nothing in this case as we are
> deleting).
>
> For the regex, . matches any character, * repeats this any number of
> times (including zero) and : matches a colon. So effectively it is
> anything followed by a colon. Since .* can include a colon, the match
> is 'greedy' and everything up to the last colon is included.

Comment: Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix